# Cannot install React subspec in CocoaPods

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

This is my current Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'atom' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 5.20.1'



  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'
  pod 'react-native-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

end



 post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     if target.name == "React"
       target.remove_from_project
     end
   end
 end
```

When I try to add this:

```
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'RCTGeolocation',
  ]
```

I get this error:

```
$ pod install
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.4
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `React` from `../node_modules/react-native`
Fetching podspec for `react-native-image-picker` from `../node_modules/react-native-image-picker`
Fetching podspec for `react-native-maps` from `../node_modules/react-native-maps`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/RCTGeolocation":
  In Podfile:
    React/RCTGeolocation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/RCTGeolocation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

I have tried `pod repo update`, but the error still occurs.

I am on React-native 0.59.  Deployment target 9.0.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue with version 0.60. I've found out that geolocation has been moved out of the react-native core.

Fixed it by using it as a separate module.

Installion instructions and docs at [react-native-geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation).

P.S. import is needed after all!

Answer (score 0):

First of all <= 0.59 and >= 0.60 use completely different pod file as core moved to pod for dependencies.

This is for 0.59 and below:

```
    pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'ART',
    'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTWebSocket', # Needed for debugging
    'RCTAnimation', # Needed for FlatList and animations running on native UI thread
    'RCTGeolocation', 
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTBlob',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTPushNotification',
    'RCTLinkingIOS'

    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]

pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
```

Do not forget to include yoga, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: btw dont forget to run yarn or npm install before installing pods